# What happened to the manager poaching question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I posted a question (https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/140813/107097) that got deleted. Why was it removed?

Answer (score 12):

It was deleted as "spam or offensive," presumably because it appears to promote a commercial interest.

Answer (score 12):

It attracted a strong negative reception including spam flags because it promoted a particular store. It also didn't ask a very clear question and there was suspicion that it didn't contain an authentic question and served only to advertise the store. While that commercial interest was obviously disclosed, overall **the moderator team confirmed the spam flags and thus it was deleted**.

Comment: Would a revised version of the question be allowed, without all of the links and references to a specific store? Seeing as the OP posted the deleted question, it may be useful to explain what could be done if they wanted to try posting it again.

Comment: @DavidK a question about how to go about poaching employees from the competition, without promotional links but with the national and cultural context, would work I think.  It'll probably get some downvotes from people who don't like poaching, but if it's well-asked it'll also get upvotes and answers.

Comment: @DavidK the poster had to post the question otherwise it could not have been deleted...

Comment: @SolarMike I mean the poster of this Meta question also posted the deleted question being discussed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (and updating the question) @DavidK, somehow I missed that this was from the OP. One issue she'll have is that she now has a question block since the question was removed as spam. If she wants to still ask an improved version of the question it's best if she confirms that here so we can look at how to do that.