# Why was my second question on poaching, without brands this time, deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Apologia again for the bother. [These answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6227/107097) refer to a "commercial interest", but I removed all brand names in https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/141179/107097. Thus what's wrong now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was deleted by the community as spam.

I have made some edits to your question to remove unnecessary links that appear promotional, including the jobs site you used and the specific offer you're making when you approach people.  What specific salary you're offering isn't central to your question, which is about how to approach store managers.